# Possible to mix rows and columns with flex box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to achieve the pictured layout purely with flex box and other css adding an extra div to enclose the images stacked in a column? My guess is that the answer is no, but I wanted to put this out there.

[image]

The HTML structure I want is something like this:

```
<div>
   <div class="tile"></div>
   <div class="tile"></div>
   <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

And not this:

```
<div>
   <div class="tile"></div>
   <div>
     <div class="tile"></div>
     <div class="tile"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes and no, where can we see your HTML structure ?

Comment: Something like this? http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/Axutc

Comment: No. As in the image above, I would like the second and third divs stacked on top of each other in a column.

Comment: The structure you want, will not.

Comment: http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html